Dependency check with liccheck fails - Expected matching RIGHT_PARENTHESIS for LEFT_PARENTHESIS, after version specifier
In a django app, with poetry as the dependency/packaging manager, I am using a library (also a django one) that is used by multiple django apps.
Those different apps are using different versions of django. So, in the pyproject.toml file of the library, the django dependency is defined like so:
django = ">=3.2.18,<4.0.0 || >=4.0.10,<4.1.0 || >=4.1.7"

while in my application I am have:
django="4.1.13"

The dependency check with liccheck is done as follows:
poetry export --without-hashes -f requirements.txt > requirements.txt
liccheck -r requirements.txt

After I run the check, it fails for with the following error message:
pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Expected matching RIGHT_PARENTHESIS for LEFT_PARENTHESIS, after version specifier
    django (>=3.2.18,<4.0.0 || >=4.0.10,<4.1.0 || >=4.1.7)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^

It seems that the django dependency from the library is affecting the dependency check.
Initially I had the 0.9.1 version of liccheck and I have already updated it to the latest 0.9.2 but with the same results.
Any idea?
